Configure Debian to connect to ONT like IPoE/DHCP router provided by the ISP
My ISP provides a pre-configured Asus router running Linaro GCC 4.6-2012.02 which connects to ONT (fibre box) via Ethernet cable. I can SSH into the router and see the WAN interface:
18: vlan10@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether fc:34:97:59:**:** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet ***.***.176.118/30 brd ***.***.176.119 scope global vlan10
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ****:****:2600:24d0::1/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ****::****:97ff:fe59:ee10/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

The goal is to configure a custom router running Debian 11 to do the same thing so that I could get rid of the ISP-provided router.
The ISP provides some details how to configure custom routers:

Connection type: IPoE or DHCP
Internet IP Address: Get Dynamically from ISP
Domain Name Server (DNS): Get Automatically from ISP
VLAN Tagging (sometimes called IPTV settings): VID: 10 / PRIO: 0
SIP ALG: Disabled
Connection Type: DHCP (with Prefix Delegation)
Domain Name Server (DNS): Get Automatically from ISP
Prefix length (or delegation size / ID): 56
DHCPv6: Checked  or  ON

The Debian box has already been configured to use VLAN. So, for this fibre WAN I tried:
auto eth0.10
iface eth0.10 inet6 dhcp
    accept_ra 2
    request_prefix 1

But it gets stuck in requesting DHCP info and never obtains an IP address from the ISP.
How to approach this problem? The funny thing is that I have root SSH access to a Linux machine (the Asus router) which already does it, so I should by all means be able to translate its settings into Debian. But how?

What's the reasoning in getting rid of the ISP supplied router?

@eyoung100 I am using my own Raspberry PI router and have no use for the ISP's Asus. Up until recently my PI was connected directly to the ONT (which itself was a DHCP server my PI could obtain lease from). But the fibre infrastructure provider (who owns and remotely controls the ONT) decided to change how they operate, which resulted in the change of required configuration. Now the Asus does it, and I just want the PI to do it instead.


Setup VLAN. If only one physical interface exists on the Debian router machine, use a managed switch with VLAN support.
In /etc/network/interfaces.d/, configure a VLAN interface with VID supplied by ISP (10 in this case):

auto eth0.10
iface eth0.10 inet dhcp
iface eth0.10 inet6 dhcp
    request_prefix 1
    accept_ra 2


Connect cable to the ONT (make sure the switch ports are tagged with VID 10).

Bring the interface up with sudo ifup eth0.10. Check that it has received a WAN IP address from the ISP.

If default route hasn't populated automatically:
a. Check the DHCP lease details in /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.10.leases, search for option routers <IP>.
b. Use that IP to add the default route: sudo ip route add default via <IP>

Get rid of the ISP-supplied router.


